# Delphi - open file from MemoryStream with associated program

Tags: delphi, stream, memorystream, delphi-xe8

Is there any way to open file from `MemoryStream` with app associated to its extension? Or I must save the file from stream to temporary folder and run it with `ShellExecute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to open file from MemoryStream with app associated to its extension?

No.

> Or I must save the file from stream to temporary folder and run it with ShellExecute?

Yes.

Processes have isolated memory space. An external process can't read your process memory.

Well, two processes can share memory with a memory mapped file. But that requires both process to agree on the protocol to share that memory. You'd need to have complete control over both processes, which I suspect you do not.